# Read a Url Returning Data In Xml Format From Client Browser Without Sending Requst To Server, Using Client Side Internet

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I Got An URL http://www.straitstimes.com/print/singapore/rss.xml# Which Will Return Data In XML Format And I Have to Make Use Of Client Internet For Retrieving The Data Instead Of Server Side Internet.

I Mean Even If There Wont Be Any Internet Access On The Server I Should Get The Data Making Use Of Client Internet

I Have Tried Using This Code

```
System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
strSource = webClient.DownloadString(url);
webClient.Dispose();
```

And Also I tried Using

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(url);
strSource = doc.InnerXml;
```

But It Didn't Help Me

And Also I Cannot Use Server For Retrieving The Data, I got To Do This From Client Browser Without Requesting To Server.

Please Suggest How Can I Do This..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this because the only way to achieve it is to use a javascript AJAX call, except that this RSS feed is not hosted on your site and the same origin policy restriction will prevent you for accessing it.

There are 2 possible workarounds for the same origin policy restriction:

- JSONP (won't work in your case because this is XML, not JSON)
- CORS

So this will only work if the remote server supports [`CORS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). And of course only in browsers that support CORS.